# Is it possible to overlap a GUI made in FoxPro?

Tags: visual-foxpro

Is there away to create a UI that overlaps with the  GUI of a program without having access to the source code but rather by monitoring clicks and keys for example ?

Comment: Yes, but I know only how to do that in VFP, though it will be seperate from the GUI you are trying to subvert to the mimic.  You can find the running window handle with OS function calls, its position, size and a host of information for which you may need for your design and create a transparent new VFP window which would read the size and position of the target application window.

Comment: And it is also possible to resize / move the original window by manipulating the invisible window.  On that new window, you would build overlay fields with, buttons, etc, which will have a new inherent behavior to overrides the behavior designed into the original VFP application.  

I have done this before, but, fair warning, it will be a significant amount of work, though not impossible.  You need to learn how to create invisible windows with OS function calls and have access to the same database or XML files etc...